# How to get json data from texarea or file in js?

Tags: javascript

There is a .txt file that contains json:

```
{
  "com": "ip",
  "res": [
    {
      "add": "04554E9",
      "m": "6773CYU",
      "default": false,
    },
    {
      "add": "4CECEC58F23",
      "m": "32DW4N",
      "default": true,
    },
    {
      "add": "6E3458",
      "m": "9ANYJ6C5ZVAM",
      "default": true,
    }
  ]
}
```

Trying to loop sort add where "default": true. Through the browser the file is in the local folder.
If you write json in the js file, everything works. The js code:

```
function loadJsonData() {
var cc = here's the json code

    var myArray = cc.res;
    var idToLookFor = true;
    
    var addrs = myArray
      .filter(function (item) {
        return item.default === idToLookFor;
      })
      .map(function (elem) {
        return elem.add;
      })
      .join(",");
console.log(addrs);
};
```

But I want to do it via file selection or textarea. I have tried all the options and I get undefined everywhere. Here are some variants I have tried:

```
const el = document.getElementById('benderform').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
function submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData(event.target);
    let obj = {};
    formData.forEach((value, key) => obj[key] = value);
    console.log(obj);
var idToLookFor = true;
    var addrs = obj.filter(function (item) {
        return item.default === idToLookFor;
      })
      .map(function (elem) {
        return elem.add;
      })
      .join(",");
      console.log(addrs);
    console.log('ok');
}</script>
<form id="benderform">
  <input name="name" value="Bender">
  <input type="submit" value="TEST">
  </form>
```

```
function loadJsonData() {
var cc = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
    var myArray = cc.res;
    var idToLookFor = true;   
    var addrs = myArray.filter(function (item) {
        return item.default === idToLookFor; }).map(function (elem) {
        return elem.add;}).join(",");
    console.log(addrs);
};
```

When using the command:

```
$.getJSON('filename.json', function(data) {
```

It returns: from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Is there any way to get this data without using the server and adding the json text directly to the js file?

Comment: Of course you can; after all, JSON is literally Javascript code.  You'd have to do that on the server side when you create the page, of course.

Comment: You don't need AJAX because you can directly read the file that the user submitted in the form. First get the file using `event.target` and then read it with `new FileReader()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a file via file input, Use a `FileReader` to read files

```js
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (event) {
  // content is your a.txt file
  const content = event.target.result;
  // here content filter logic
};

reader.readAsText(file);
```

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter').

Comment: filter is a method that is only available on array types. Access `content.res` and use the filter method

Comment: const content = event.target.result;
    const myArray = content.res;
    const idToLookFor = true;  
    const addrs = myArray.filter(function (item) {
console.log(myArray); gives undefined. 
console.log(content); outputs json data

Comment: JSON.parse(content)